# Navigation sliding line on hover - when no item is 'current' or 'selected'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have a sliding line on my main navigation, so on hover the line animates/slides to the item you've hovered over from it's current position (which should be the current page).

Example: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/Yjqrqo

The problem I'm having is when there is no `current_menu_item` class on a menu item it breaks.

80% of the time there will be a 'selected' menu item but there are some instances when you're on terms, privacy, contact (footer links) pages where there isn't a main nav item to relate to.

Ideally when there isn't a selected item I'd like the line to fade in on hover, then slide about from there. Then if you don't click anything and leave the menu again the line will fade out. But I'm open to suggestions.

```js
$(function() {
    var $el, leftPos, newWidth, $mainNav = $(".site-nav__list");
    $mainNav.append("<div class='site-nav__line'></div>");
    var $magicLine = $(".site-nav__line");
    $magicLine
        .width($(".current-menu-item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current-menu-item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $(".site-nav__list li a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* MIXIN */

@mixin clearfix() {
 
 &:before,
 &:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
 }
 
 &:after {
  clear: both;
 }
}

/* Body */

body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0;
}

/* Header */

.page-head {
 background: white;
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  @include clearfix;
 padding: 0 30px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.page-head__logo {
 background-image: none;
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 text-shadow: none;
 width: 200px;
}

/* Nav */

.site-nav {
 display: block;
  float: right;
 text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}

.site-nav__list {
  list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.site-nav__list li {
 background: none;
  display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
 &.current-menu-item {}
}

.site-nav__list a {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 900;
 padding: 30px 15px;
 transition: color .15s;
 text-shadow: none;
  
  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}

/* Underline */

.site-nav__line {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="page-head">
    <a href="#" class="page-head__logo">Logo Here </a>
    <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul class="site-nav__list">
            <li class="site-nav__item current-menu-item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">About</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Looooonger Title</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Company</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">About</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Login</a></li>
            <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link amp">Apply</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: what is your problem here, I cannot understand your problem

Comment: The CodePen I posted works, mostly. The problem is when there is no `current-menu-item` class added. When that is the case, I need the line to be hidden. Then once a menu item is hovered over the line fades in. Then it should slide to the other menu items if you hover over them. If you leave the menu it should fade out again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is no `current-menu-item` you will get `$(".current-menu-item a").position()` as `undefined`. And then the error in console

> Cannot read property 'left' of `undefined`

So you have to check that `current-menu-item` is exist or not in `width()` & `css()` method like following.

```
var $magicLine = $(".site-nav__line"),
    $currentMenu = $(".current-menu-item"); //added this line

$magicLine
    .width($currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.width() : 0) //chnaged this line
    .css("left", $currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.find("a").position().left : 0) //chnaged this line
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
```

**UPDATE FOR MOVING MOUSE QUICKLY ISSUE:**
To fade in the line when there isn't a `current_menu_item` you have to make some change in `hover` event. and for quick mouse move issue you can use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

```
var hoverOut;

$(".site-nav__list li a").hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(hoverOut);

  $el = $(this);
  leftPos = $el.position().left;
  newWidth = $el.parent().width();

  if (!$magicLine.width()) {
    $magicLine.stop().hide().css({
      left: leftPos,
      width: newWidth
    }).fadeIn(400);
  } else {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      opacity: 1,
      left: leftPos,
      width: newWidth
    });
  }
}, function() {
  hoverOut = setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$currentMenu.length) {
      $magicLine.fadeOut(400, function() {
        $magicLine.css({
          left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
          width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
      });
    } else {
      $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
      });
    }
  }, 400);
});
```

**UPDATED PEN LINK:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBZwbZ

Comment: That's looking great! Can you think of a way to fade in/out the line when there isn't a `current_menu_item` rather than slide in from the left? It would still slide along when you hovered over the other items but I think it would be nice if it faded in initially? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm on my phone at the moment but I'll have a check when I'm back on a computer! Does it fade out as well when you remove the mouse from the nav? Probably not that important but not sure if I mentioned it

Comment: I think that's almost there! Only problem I can see is that if you move your mouse quickly to a nav item it doesn't seem to register and the line fades out again. Does that happen for you?

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope it will solve your issue. @user1406440

Comment: This looks like it works really, really well!! Is the delay when you remove the mouse just so it doesn't fade out if the mouse moves too fast etc? Just gives it a bit of time incase there's a glitch? I like it as if you remove your mouse for a second before moving to another item it doesn't break. I might reduce the delay a little bit but I guess not too low as it's there for a reason?

Comment: You can reduce the delay and check. I think atleast **200** would be better. @user1406440

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but best not to remove it entirely. I think I've used `inline-block` for the items so maybe a `float` to reduce the 1 or 2 pixel gap would help as well. Thanks a lot, this is great - who knew it would be so difficult haha :)

Comment: Glad to help. :) @user1406440

Comment: Hey man, not sure if you can help with this so no problem if not! I just noticed on my mobile menu (which doesn't need this script) I had to tap twice for a link to work. Have you come across that before? If I remove the script it works fine so just wondering if it can be amended or only 'active' above a certain screen width?

Answer (score 3):

When you don't have `.current-menu-item` then `$(".current-menu-item").width()` and `$(".current-menu-item a").position().left` will return undefined so that it will crash. Here I have made little change on your code.

```
$(".site-nav__list li a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });
```

With

```
$(".site-nav__list li a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    if ($magicLine.width() >0) {
      $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
      });
    } else {
      $magicLine.width(newWidth).css("left", leftPos).fadeIn(3000);
    }
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});
```

And

```
$magicLine.stop().animate({
    left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
    width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
});
```

with

```
if ($currentMenu.length) {
       $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
       } else {
        $magicLine.fadeOut('slow'); 
       }
```

```js
$(function(){
 var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
        $mainNav = $(".site-nav__list");
    
    $mainNav.append("<div class='site-nav__line'></div>");
    var $magicLine = $(".site-nav__line"),
        $currentMenu = $(".current-menu-item");
  
    $magicLine
        .width($currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.width() : 0)
        .css("left", $currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.find("a").position().left : 0)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

 $(".site-nav__list li a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        if ($magicLine.width() >0) {
          $magicLine.show().stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
          });
        } else {
          $magicLine.width(newWidth).css("left", leftPos).fadeIn(3000);
        }
    }, function() {
   if ($currentMenu.length) {
       $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
       } else {
        $magicLine.fadeOut('slow'); 
       }
        
            
    });
});
```

```css
/* MIXIN */

@mixin clearfix() {
 
 &:before,
 &:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
 }
 
 &:after {
  clear: both;
 }
}

/* Body */

body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0;
}

/* Header */

.page-head {
 background: white;
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  @include clearfix;
 padding: 0 30px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.page-head__logo {
 background-image: none;
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 text-shadow: none;
 width: 200px;
}

/* Nav */

.site-nav {
 display: block;
  float: right;
 text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}

.site-nav__list {
  list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.site-nav__list li {
 background: none;
  display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
 &.current-menu-item {}
}

.site-nav__list a {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 900;
 padding: 30px 15px;
 transition: color .15s;
 text-shadow: none;
  
  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}

/* Underline */

.site-nav__line {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header class="page-head">

    <a href="#" class="page-head__logo">Logo Here </a>

    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul class="site-nav__list">
        <li class="site-nav__item "><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">About</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Looooonger Title</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Company</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">About</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Login</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link amp">Apply</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, makes sense. The only problem with the example is I still want the line to slide from link to link, that worked fine. It's just when there is no `current_menu_item` and you hover over a link it should fade in initially. Then it should slide along to the other items like it already did. Does that makes sense? Sorry if not!

Comment: @user1406440 I have updated above hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey there, I think that's pretty close! I think it'd be nice if the line faded out when you move the mouse away from the nav links rather than slide off to the left, what do you think? Thanks again!

Comment: @user1406440 ok give me some time I will update my answer

Comment: @user1406440 Answer has been updated hope this is what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Appreciate it! I didn't think it'd be so tricky but that's my lack of JS knowledge. I think the effect is working now but if you move quickly between the items it doesn't seem to respond/loses sync - does that happen for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176604/discussion-between-kiran-shahi-and-user1406440).

Answer (score 1):

Just before About list item, adding a `li` tag that has `anchor` tag with style of `display:none` solves the issue.

`<li class="site-nav__item current-menu-item"><a href="#" style="display:none"></a></li>`

Using this extra item in the pages that does not belong to main menu items should be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That seems like a solution but I think I'm going to do a bit of digging and see if I can get the item to fade in rather than slide in from the left for now. This is a good option to have if that's not achievable though :)

Comment: Hope you achieve what you want :0)