# How to make a line slide beside a hovered <li>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-transitions

Here I added pseudo-class to li on hover its opacity 1. when I hover :after is fading how can I make it as its looks like moving on a straight line without faded.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 700ms cubic-bezier(0.155, 0.930, 0.430, 0.990);
}

li:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translatey(30px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not really clear what you are looking for here

Comment: @charlietfl it will looks like this stackoverflow.com/q/51370829/9004424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs js for your demand to work. The example you gave used jquery, but I wrote a version using pure js

The line is not a li::after but the parent's ul::after, it is made so that we can get the offsetTop and offsetHeight and apply style changes that is relative to the parents

```js
let root = document.documentElement.style

function magicline(item) {
  root.setProperty('--navlinetop', `${item.offsetTop}px`)
  root.setProperty('--navlineheight', `${item.offsetHeight}px`)
}

function initiatelist() {
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li')
  for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
      magicline(event.target)
    })
  }
}

initiatelist()
```

```css
:root {
  --navlinetop: 0px;
  --navlineheight: 0px;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em;
  top: 0;
  width: 10ch;
  list-style-type: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

li {
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  right: -5px;
  top: var(--navlinetop);
  height: var(--navlineheight);
  width: 3px;
  background: #fa4;
  transition: top .3s, height .3s
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In the middle of the item :after travel

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: it will looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/51370829/9004424

Comment: that requires js, I'll try

Comment: Look at how I did it.

Comment: You updated your answer now working fine.